# push item to specific array object key

Tags: javascript

how i can push a item on object expecific?
had follow structure :

```
//construction  
 const arrStr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
 var finalObj = { };
 var objArray = {vhCal: [], vhRef: [], vhOcup: [], vhIlu: [], vhAcs: []};
 for(let x = 0; x < arrStr.length ; x++ )
{
    const val = arrStr[x];
    finalObj[val] = objArray;
}
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4q6x.png)
if i try to add a item to specific sub-object array, the item was added to all keys...

```
//assign
finalObj["a"].vhAcs.push('potato')
// output :
// a:
// vhAcs: ["potato"]
// vhCal: []
// vhIlu: []
// vhOcup: []
// vhRef: []
// b:
// vhAcs: ["potato"]
// vhCal: []
// vhIlu: []
// vhOcup: []
// vhRef: []
// c:
// vhAcs: ["potato"]
// vhCal: []
// vhIlu: []
// vhOcup: []
// vhRef: []
```

only want add to 'a' key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new object inside the loop instead of setting the same object to all keys:

```js
const arrStr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const finalObj = {};
for (let x = 0; x < arrStr.length; x++) {
  const val = arrStr[x];
  finalObj[val] = {
    vhCal: [],
    vhRef: [],
    vhOcup: [],
    vhIlu: [],
    vhAcs: []
  };
}

finalObj.a.vhCal.push('foo');
console.log(finalObj);
```

Or, use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arrStr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const finalObj = Object.fromEntries(
  arrStr.map(key => [
    key,
    {
      vhCal: [],
      vhRef: [],
      vhOcup: [],
      vhIlu: [],
      vhAcs: []
    }
  ])
);

finalObj.a.vhCal.push('foo');
console.log(finalObj);
```